# Windows 10 booting partition - no such device

Tags: windows, boot, bios, grub

I have a dualboot of Windows 10 (on SSD) and Ubuntu (Hard Drive). Everything was working fine until my BIOS updated itself automatically.

Now I cannot boot my Windows partiton from GRUB, instead i have to boot it from BIOS or it randomly starts to work.

The error message i recieve:(from selectiong my Windows boot in GRUB)

error: no such device: device_id.
error: disk 'hd1,gpt1' not found.

Please help :)

Comment: Have you tried booting into your Ubuntu installation and running “sudo os-prober && sudo update-grub”? Or maybe it is a nice idea to install rEFInd; it looks better and directly can boot your Linux kernel and chain load Windows

Comment: @ Varun Narravula 
I have now tried both commands and still have the same issue. And what would installing rEFInd do, except change the appearance of GRUB or does it also have special tools to fix issues?
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: rEFInd is a bootloader/boot manager alternative to GRUB. It can chainload GRUB and the Windows bootloader, or it can alternatively directly boot your Linux kernel just like GRUB does, using the EFI stub loader that is built into the kernel itself. You can install with a PPA from Rod Smith and use the refind-install command with your EFI partition mounted on /boot/efi. Basically, GRUB may not be detecting your EFI partition correctly, so rEFInd dynamically detects bootloaders each boot; if rEFInd doesn’t find specific bootloaders, you would have to manually install it using external media.